# $x^2 +1$ is invertible in $Q[x]/(x^4 −3x^2 +6x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Why is $x^2 +1$ is invertible in $Q[x]/(x^4 −3x^2 +6x)$?

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

By the Chinese remainder theorem one has that
$$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^4 - 3x^2 +6x)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x)} \times \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^3 - 3x + 6)}$$
is a product of fields, and the image of $x^2 + 1$ in each factor is nonzero.